# Is VisualStudio 2010 built with WPF/XAML?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I had a crash with the new Release Candidate and the details suggested something went awry with WPF. Is it the case that at least some of the UI in the new release is built using WPF and XAML?

Comment: I hope you reported the crash at http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/? Unless you don't want the bug to be fixed?

Comment: You are not alone.... i have the same issue, and cannot create a WPF project or open a XAML file. If you create an issue on the Connect site, can you make sure you update your post here with the link?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010).

- The IDE shell built with [Windows Presentation Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) (WPF)
- The internals have been redesigned using [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_Extensibility_Framework) (MEF)

Answer (score 3):

There is a patch available:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/15/patch-for-vs-2010-rc-intellisense-crash-issue-now-available.aspx

If you specify what you were doing when the crash happened you might get better help.  The patch above seems to be related to intellisense.  It still may fix your issue even if it isn't due to an intellisense issue as Scott mentions in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. Look at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010). I quote:

> The IDE shell has been rewritten using
>   the Windows Presentation Foundation
>   (WPF), whereas the internals have
>   been redesigned using Managed
>   Extensibility Framework (MEF) that
>   offers more extensibility points than
>   previous versions of the IDE that
>   enabled add-ins to modify the behavior
>   of the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: There is now a patch for the second intellisense/UIA issue in the RC.  You can read about it [on the Visual Studio Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/02/second-patch-now-available-for-intellisense-crashes-in-vs-2010-rc.aspx) and [download it here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=27019&wa=wsignin1.0).

---

In addition to the mentions about the shell in other answers, the editor also uses WPF for UI.  Assuming this is one of the Intellisense/UIA-related crashes, it was likely the editor that caused the crash you are seeing.  There are two known Intellisense/UIA crashing bugs in the RC; the [larger of the two](http://blogs.msdn.com/visualstudio/archive/2010/02/09/intellisense-crash-in-ui-automation.aspx) has a [patch available](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=26662).  The other has been fixed internally, but there is no patch available for it at this time.

(I'm a developer on the editor team)