# Give application the same visual appearance as Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

This might be an easy one to answer as I'm probably just Googling for the incorrect search terms.

I'd like to change the visual appearance of my application to look more like the interface of Visual Studio 2013. Now with VS you can choose between three color themes (blue, dark and light). I'm trying to Google for ways that I can give my application that sort of look but any search for "theme" or "color theme" results in plenty of hits for how to choose a different color theme for VS.

I'm not so much interested in the colors as such but more the "flat" appearance for lack of a better word. Notice how my application has the standard Windows frame, standard minimize, maximize and close buttons at the top right and how the form's title bar, menu strip and tool strip are all different colors. On the Visual Studio UI, these are all one color and so appears to form a single unit. I also like how the form doesn't have any more border around it than is really necessary. The form basically consists of a "header" at the top (combined title bar, menu strip and tool strip) and a status strip at the bottom. Between those there is nothing but usable real estate, no silly border around the edge.

[image: Example]

Is there an easy way to achieve this for my own applications?

Answer (score 4):

<s>This isn't possible with WinForms.</s>
It's possible, but really really hard to achieve and not recommendable.
You need Windows Presentation Foundation.

Why?

1. First of all you need hardware acceleration. The UI in WPF is DirectX rather than GDI+ (WinForms) so it can make use of the acceleration and processing available in DirectX, and work in 3D.
2. Visual Studio it self is [build with WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332010/is-visualstudio-2010-built-with-wpf-xaml).

---

If you want a fresh modern Look for your WinForms Application i would recommend [Metro for WinForms](https://github.com/dennismagno/metroframework-modern-ui) (WinForms on steroids).

You also should look at [ComponentOne Studio WinForms Edition](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/C061ECBA-AFE7-4590-A0EC-76AF58096E46). Maybe one of the 25 designed themes for WinForms suits you.

Comment: Actually it is possible by using custom drawing, but it is way an overhead compared to WPF.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use WPF for the same

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7a4362a7-fe5d-4f9d-bc7b-0c0dc272fe31

For Screenshots:

https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui/wiki/Screenshots